# How to debug CSS website on Samsung Galaxy S5 default browser?

Tags: android, jquery, galaxy

EDIT : jQuery and jQuery UI were responsible for this bug. See my answer at the bottom.

---

I need to debug a website that shows strangely on a Samsung Galaxy S5 mobile. I believe the default browser should be UC Browser but I have no way to test it. I have no access to such mobile phone.

User Agent is :

```
    Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; fr-ca; SM-G900W8 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.6 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

I have a list of squared items that shows well on every browser (Chrome, Safari, IE, Opera..., Firefox,...) with media queries, but on this one, a part of the list is hidden (we can see the [top of next items that's chopped on that screenshot the client sent me](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3273079/Screenshot_2014-08-11-09-52-52.png)).

Any idea about this?

Thank you!

Comment: Quick solution. Andriod native browsers are know to not work nice. GOogle has had issues with samsung for their browser 'differences'
In short, no matter what devices your site works on, it will always be different on samsungs. 
the only way around this is to style around for samsung browsers particularly

Comment: [Check if this works](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)

Comment: @bhargavg Thank you for you comment but I don't have access to any mobile

Comment: @Jonny Thank you but still I need to be able to debug it... I have no idea what causes this overflow hidden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a built-in emulator in Google Chrome which can be accessed in the Developer Tools window. The Emulation tab is in the bottom-most bar of the Developer Tools window, easy to miss. Drag that panel up, choose the Emulation tab and select your device. Click on Emulate and begin debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had in deed no idea that this tab existed in dev tools. Very interesting. The only problem is that there is no option for Galaxy S5 (only S4). Is there any add-on?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Maybe the non-stable version has it. Link: http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel

Comment: thank you for this idea too, but I can't install it on OS X (Chrome quits right when I try to launch it)

Comment: I was able to launch it after all on another computer, and I still have no Galaxy S5 available in Device list

Comment: If you want to get super serious about emulation on desktop, theres the built in emulator, Google has some seriously good apps too. Heres a link to a few http://www.awwwards.com/15-great-chrome-extensions-for-web-designers-and-developers.html
I don't think that they included dimensions in there. Good luck

Comment: Are you sure these extensions include cell phone emulation? Dimensions in deed does, but have fewer devices than the developer tool Emulation tab :/. I have discovered now that Javascript is causing the bug, as soon as I include jQuery library, it bugs. I am trying it with the newest version right now.

Comment: OK I was able to confirm that multiple versions of jQuery alone causes this problem, even the last version available. I will update the question

Answer (score 1):

## Easy:

*(If you haven't done before enable debugging by usb on your android device)*
1. Connect device with usb to your computer
2. open chrome dev tools
3. open Three vertical dots > More tools > Remote Devices
[image]
4. Then click on your desired device, and then click on Inspect

Answer (score 0):

OK I found that I had to use the latest version of jQuery AND jQuery UI in order to clear that bug. Very strange bug I never seen in many years of development... it would happen only on GS5, not even GS4 and GS3! but now it's solved, so thank you for your help!